# Git Tig - problems with shortcut for pushing from main view

Tags: git, tig

I am working a lot with Tig and wanted to further personalize it for myself by using bindings.
Everything is working as expected, except pushing from main view into the actual, checked-out branch. (Pushing from the refs view is no problem at all.)

The binding I am using is:

```
bind refs P !?git push origin %(ref)
```

And:

```
bind main P !?git push origin %(repo:head)
```

The problem is that the state variable `%(repo:head)` should be the one I want to use, but is not working.

`(Error msg: "Failed to format arguments")`

Did someone already encounter this behavior?
Does someone know how I can make the pushing work from the main view?

---

For information: 
I am using Ubuntu in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, this binding seems OK.
Maybe some other binding override it, could you try other key except `P`?
Or try to unbind it first like following:

```
bind main P none
bind main P !?git push origin %(repo:head)
```

Comment: Hi Pham, thanks for your help.
Unfortunately, unbinding did not help.
As soon as I use ```%(repo:head)``` I get the mentioned ```"Failed to format arguments"``` error.


Also binding to another Key (I tried "W") did not help.